# Como declarar uma condição ternária no XAML como parametro para uma CustomMarkupExtension

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Olá estou começando a trabalhar com o WPF e criei uma **Custom Markup Extension** partindo [deste tutorial](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mamta_m/creating-a-custom-markup-extension-in-wpf/). A intenção dessa Markup Extension é simular as condições declarativas que são encontradas em WebFrameworks como o [Angular2](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf) ou o [VueJS](https://it.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html) para a web, por exemplo:

```
<!-- se não atende a condição, não insere o elemento -->
<div *ngIf="condition">...</div> <!-- angular -->
<div v-if="condition">...</div>  <!-- vue -->

<!-- retorna para a variável -->
<input type="text" [disabled]="condition" /> <!-- angular -->
<input type="text" :disabled="condition" /> <!-- vue -->

<!-- atribui uma classe ao elemento -->
<div [ngClass]="{ 'foo': condition }"></div> <!-- angular -->
<div :class="{ 'foo': condition }"></div> <!-- vue -->
```

Como `XAML` é bem parecido com `HTML` e já tenho costume de trabalhar com esses frameworks, o que procuro é simplificar ao máximo a forma de comparação inbutindo a variação de uma variável a partir dessa condição. Assim eu poderia, por exemplo mudar o texto de um botão, a visibilidade, a cor, etc...

Abaixo está minha Markup:

```
namespace WPF
{
    public class If : MarkupExtension
    {
        public bool Condition { get; set; }
        public object True { get; set; }
        public object False { get; set; }

        public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            if (Condition & (True != null && False != null))
                return Condition ? True : False;
            else
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Inputs cannot be blank");
        }
    }
}
```

A intenção dessa Markup Extension é literalmente imitar o operador If para operações tenárias, Tendo seu uso assim:

```
<Window x:Class="WPF.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPF">
    <Grid>

        <!-- ocultar ou mostrar -->
        <TextBlock Visibility="{fn:If Condition=/* ?? */, True='Visible', False='Colapsed'}"/>

        <!-- mudança de variável -->
        <TextBlock Text="{fn:If Condition=/* ?? */, True='Is true!', False='Is not true!'}"/>

        <!-- Mudança de estilo (como as classes html) -->
        <TextBlock Text="{fn:If Condition=/* ?? */, True={DynamicResource Foo}, False={DynamicResource Bar}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Meu problema é que não sei como posso declarar uma condição diretamente no XAML usando o `Binding` de uma variável. Imaginemos que na minha classe `MainWindow.cs` eu tenha uma variável assim:

```
namespace WPF
{
    public partial class MainWindow
    {
        private int randomNumber { get; set; }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            randomNumber = rnd.Next(0, 10);
        }
    }
}
```

Como eu faço para fazer uma comparação ternária diretamente no XAML? Por exemplo, como eu verifico se o numero é maior que 6, ou seja `(randomNumber > 6 ? 'Is true!' : 'Is not true!')`

### Edit

Eu até encontrei essa [solução](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47438428/ternary-operator-in-xaml-in-xamarin-forms) mas não concordo que seja obrigado a criar isso tudo para atender uma operação ternária simples, afinal se eu tiver que criar uma classe e um converter para cada possibiliade/atributo, eu entenderia como uma falha na linguagem...

Comment: Acredito que [naquela solução](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47439998/8093394) a proposta de usar um `Converter` se enquadrava melhor para o problema. No caso de um operador ternário como markup, o ponto chave é interpretar a expressão (no caso `randomNumber > 6`).

Comment: sim, com certeza, o problema é que eu preciso interpretá-la na passagem de valor. ex: `function foo(2 + 2)`.